# Why I am getting the below error? I interchanged the class names and there was no error

Tags: java, inheritance, program-entry-point

[Here i changed the base and child classes but still my main class is Overloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leH7F.png)[image: Please click here for the screenshot of my question]

I am executing this in java 8. I tried interchanging the class name. While i did that, I also shuffled the main method. I was getting no errors. It is the only scenario where i am getting an error. I am not getting why. Please help.

Comment: Is there any rationale behind your shuffling around? If you wanted to find out that a subclass may inherit members of its superclass, but not the other way round, well, you did.

Answer (score 1):

In your Eclipse ide press **run configuration**. Ensure that in the main class is written   "Practice.Pervert"

I managed to reproduce your problem. If inside this textfield is written the Orloading the exact same error appears.

Comment: I checked **run configuration**. In the textfield,is written Overloading.

`package Practice;

class Pervert {
 public void nothing()
 {
  System.out.println("This is pervert class");
 }
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("main");

 }

}
 
public class Overloading extends Pervert{

 public void something()
 {
  System.out.println("this is overloading");
 }
 
}
 `
Its getting executed

Comment: To be Precise it should be Practice.Pervert.

Comment: @AbhilashPadhee which class contains your main method? Which class are you trying to get that main method from?

Comment: @Pshemo main method is in overloading class. But after interchanging the child and parent class, i am not getting why its not throwing any error.

Comment: Because in your run configuration you need to specify the other Class as a main class. When I say run configuration I mean the Eclise Run Configuration you will find it in the Run section.

Comment: @AbhilashPadhee Try to read error message. It says that main method couldn't be found in `Overloading` method which means that this is the class from where you are trying to run that `main` method, but since you moved your method to derived class and still are trying to run it from superclass (which now doesn't have that method) you are informed about it by error message. Try to save your project and update class from which you are trying to run main method (you can use `Alt+Shift+X` then `J`, or right-click on your code -> Run As -> Java Application ... then select class with main method)

Comment: @Pshemo Agreed. I got the picture but wanna ask a question. In run config my main class is still overloading and i have modified my code something like this:

package Practice; 
class Pervert { public void nothing()
 { System.out.println("This is pervert class"); } 
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {  System.out.println("main"); } } 
public class Overloading extends Pervert{
 public void something() { System.out.println("this is overloading"); } } 

Here main method is still not present in overloading class yet i am able to execute.How?

Comment: @AbhilashPadhee I am guessing that you didn't save your code after that change so `class` files still contain information from previously compiled `.java` code. Hard to say without actually seeing what you did and how you are running your code.